# derivative definition problem $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x^3) - f(0) / x$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I am attempting a problem from a textbook and having difficulty getting set up because I haven't seen the $f(x^3)$ before. How would I go about proving this?

My thoughts are that we know $f$ is continuous at 0 since it is differentiable but am still unsure how to proceed
 The problem reads:

Let $f$ be differentiable at $x=0$. Prove that
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \dfrac{f(x^{3}) - f(0)}{x} = 0$$

Comment: Hello! Welcome to this site! A hint: consider $g(x)=f(x^3)$. What is $g(0)$? How do you express the limit at hand using $g$? Also, let me guess: isn't this problem taken from a section about the Chain Rule?

Comment: Truth be told I am helping my friend with this and this is one of their problems for a test review. Oddly enough they haven't covered Chain Rule yet which leaves me extra puzzled. To answer your question, $g(0) = f(0)$ so I can probably rewrite $f(x^3)$ as $g(x)$ and $f(0)$ as $g(0)$?

Comment: Yes, then how do you express the given limit using $g$? Using the Chain Rule, the answer follows immediately. Without it, we can still solve the problem but it is annoying to write it in a comment, so I'll add an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $g(x)=f(x^3)$. Then, we have $g(0)=f(0)$ and $\frac{f(x^3)-f(0)}{x}=\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x}$. So, by definition, the given limit is $g'(0)$. Note that, since $f$ and $x^3$ are differentiable, then $g$ is also differentiable, by the Chain Rule.

Moreover, the Chain Rule says that $g'(x)=3x^2f'(x^3)$. It follows that $g'(0)=0$.

---

**Other method (without the Chain Rule)**: we have $\frac{f(x^3)-f(0)}{x}=x^2 \frac{f(x^3)-f(0)}{x^3}$.

By substitution $t=x^3$, we have $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x^3)-f(0)}{x^3}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(t)-f(0)}{x}=f'(0)}$, so by Limit Laws, $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x^3)-f(0)}{x}=0 \times f'(0)=0$$